# Ember index data -vs- show data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How do people deal with index data (the data usually shown on index pages, like a customer list) -vs- the model detail data?

When somebody goes to the customer/index route -- they only need access to a small subset of the full customer resource.   Since I am dealing with legacy data, my customer model has > 10 relationships.   It seems wasteful to have the api return a complete and full customer representation for every customer just to render a list/select/index view.

I know those relationships are somewhat lazy-loaded, but it still takes effort on the backend to pull all those relationships in.   For some relationships (such as customer->invoices) this could be a large list of ids.

Answer (score 0):

I feel answers to this can be very opinionated. But my two cents:

The API you are drawing on for your data should have an end-point to fetch the subset of data you're interested in, e.g. `/api/mini-customer` vs `/api/customer`.

You can then either define two separate models (one to represent the model in the list and one to represent the detailed view), or simply populate the original model with the subset of data and merge the extra data in at a later point.

**That said**, I've also seen plenty of cases such as the one you describe, where you load all data initially and just display the subset to begin with. If it's reasonable that the data will eventually be used and your page-load constraints can handle it, then this can be an acceptable approach.

Comment: Thanks.    The hows, wheres, and whens of "merge the extra data" is what I am curious about.    Most of the CRUD examples are incredibly simple.  Real world data is more... complicated.     In my invoice_ids example I'd suspect it's under 1:100 that those will be needed for any given session.

Comment: I might add, I think I am leaning towards the 'dual-model' approach.   Those could be reused for select lookups, etc.    Just seems like a waste to define most models twice.